# Find and replace all strings in body, but ignore attributes with string value in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Using Python, I would like to find and replace all instances of "foo" to bar, but ignore any instances of "foo" that happen to be attribute values.

Example:

```html
<p><a class="foo" id="foo" href="foo.html">foo</a>foo</a></p>
```

Output expected:

```html
<p><a class="foo" id="foo" href="foo.html"><span class="fixed">bar</span></a></p>
```

Output I'm getting:

```html
<p><a class="bar" id="bar" href="bar.html"><span class="fixed">bar</span></a></p>
```

In that example, the attributes also get changed.

Code snippet :

```py
html_content="<p><a class="foo" id="foo" href="foo.html"><span class="fixed">bar</span></a></p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
element_text = soup.body.find(lambda element: "foo" in element.text)
replace_text = str(element_text).replace("foo","bar")
```

I tried this way but this code replaces the attributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your values in your elements you could try to replace `<foo` with `<bar`.

As a workaround you could replace `class=\"bar\"` with `placeholder`, than replace all foos and replace `placeholder` with `class=\"bar\"`.